# Is "monkey around" offensive?

Tags: offensive-language

Someone asked me for something and I said, "Do you need it right now, or do I have a couple hours to monkey around with it?"  They got really quiet.  While certainly unprofessional, is this also somehow offensive?

Comment: You weren’t by chance addressing a simian, were you?

Comment: You weren't by chance addressing someone who is black, were you?

Comment: @Andrew Leach It was on the phone so possibly.

Comment: @Mikey Some people are hypersensitive to words that are offensive in *other* contexts. As Andrew notes, 'monkey' is considered deeply offensive by some black people. I had a similar experience once where I was sharply rebuked for using the word 'unmolested' when asking if I could remove my name badge while working on some non-customer service tasks in a retail store. See also, the long and storied history of [Niggardly.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66602/do-people-really-think-muslin-has-something-to-do-with-muslim)

Comment: I can't think of anyone who might have been offended if you'd used 'tinker' instead.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: *Tinker* can refer to people of the  [Irish Traveler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_people) ethnic group.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think the term is necessarily offensive, but maybe your cavalier attitude toward the "something" was what gave the person pause. Maybe he or she thought you should handle whatever the something was with more care than implied by monkeying around with it.

Comment: JLG, I think the problem, if any, is more likely to be the offer to supply the something right away, without taking time to improve it or to figure out if it will work.

Comment: @jwpat7, It could be, but without knowing what the "something" is, we're all just guessing. It could have been something concrete, like a tool, or maybe a computer file Mikey was supposed to be working on.

Comment: It was a computer file, but I've probably said the same of tools I've been borrowing and mechanical devices I've been repairing/modifying.

Answer (score 2):

The term is not offensive, however, it is usually used to describe an effort (to improve something) that does not succeed, so maybe that's why the person got quiet.

Answer (score 1):

To "monkey around" is to NOT do something (or take something) seriously. If it was a work situation, that might be "professionally" (as opposed to "socially") offensive.

Answer (score 0):

The context you used your phrase is not offensive. However, the phrase itself, is.

As some comments had pointed out, there is some hypersensitivity surrounding that phrase. Most of the hypersensitivity is due to [racial implications](http://www.authentichistory.com/diversity/african/3-coon/6-monkey/index.html).

While I'm sure you meant no offense (your context even proves it), chances are that you probably were talking to someone either of ethnicity or someone who is just sensitive to ethnic slurs.

Answer (score 0):

to **monkey around** [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/121266?rskey=TMasLM&result=2#eid36275772)

> 2. intr. colloq. (orig. U.S.). To play mischievous or foolish tricks. Also: to fool or mess about or around; to tinker, tamper, or interfere
>      (frequently with about with, around with, or with).

As in:

> 1989   Your Business    In financial terms there is no lower end; we
>   can always monkey around with the shares.

It is listed in dictionaries as either colloquial or idiomatic and not offensive. But in these times it is best to leave the *monkey* out of all conversation.